# How to run rspec tests using selenium through cron

Tags: ruby, rspec, continuous-integration, cron

I'm having trouble running rspec tests through cron.  I'm using selenium to access firefox and test logging into a page.  All my files work properly when executed outside of cron.    From what I've read, the problem could be that cron needs a display environment to run programs like firefox.  This is where I'm stuck, how can I set up a display environment for selenium to start up firefox from within cron.

I've tried setting the display a couple ways in the crontab..

```
*/25 * * * * /home/justin/test.sh --display=:0 > testlog

*/25 * * * * DISPLAY=:0; /home/justin/test.sh > testlog;
```

I've also tried setting it in the script..

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/justin/widget_ui_testing/

DISPLAY=:0

/home/justin/.rvm/bin/rvm exec /home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rspec 
-fdoc /home/justin/widget_ui_testing/spec/requests/log_in_spec.rb
```

The error message I keep getting is

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
# ./spec/requests/log_in_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to change selenium's code to run firefox with a specified display. Or if I've missed something along the way.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start Xvfb first. I recommend you to use [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem that simplifies interaction with Xvfb. Also take a look into readme it has similar use cases.

Also take a look into this [blog post](http://iafonov.github.com/blog/setup-jenkins-to-run-headless-selenium.html) about setting up Jenkins and headless.

P.S: Just a suggestion - don't use cron for such purpose use CI tool. I recommend [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) it can do builds both by polling SCM and periodically (your exact use case).